# Get series value in a table not in a series in another table in ms sql 200

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table, My first table look like this

tblRecords

```
Series_Start    Series_End
1001            1095
```

And my second table

tblDetail

```
Series_StartUsed    Series_EndUsed
1011                 1021
1051                 1060
```

My goal is to select series in tblRecords not in tblDetail. Sample output is

```
Series_Start    Series_End
1001            1010
1031            1050
1061            1095
```

Any idea what is the correct SQL script with this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, this query might work (not tested):

```
select zx.Series_start, zx.Series_End from (
    select r.Series_start, 
           r.Series_End, 
           case when (select 1 from tblDetail d where (d.Series_StartUsed <= r.Series_End and (d.Series_EndUsed >= r.Series_start or d.Series_StartUsed >= r.Series_Start))) is null then 0 else 1 end as isUsed
    from tblRecords r) zx
where zx.isUsed = 0
```

I might have messed up the actual condition (third select variable), so play around with it if needed as I don't have a way to easily test it right now.

Also, the above query is pretty inefficient so it is not appropriate if you want to use it for extremely large datasets as something routine. You will probably need to write a stored procedure if you want to do that.

Comment: stil with error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. "